# Linear Algebra by Lang - Problem 1.4.18

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help with this problem:

> **Problem 1.4.18** Let $B_1, \ldots, B_m$ be vectors of length $1$ in $n$-space, and mutually perpendicular, that is $B_i \cdot B_j = 0$ if $i \neq j$. Let $A$ be a vector in $n$-space, and let $c_i$ be the component of $A$ along $B_i$. Let $x_1, \ldots, x_m$ be numbers. Show that
>
> $$\vert\vert A - (c_1B_1 + \cdots + c_mB_m)\vert\vert \leq \vert\vert A - (x_1B_1 + \cdots + x_mB_m)\vert\vert.$$

I've been trying to figure out what this problem means geometrically to help me prove it. If I were to take $m = n$ then it seems to me that $c_1B_1+\dots+c_nB_n$ is only the vector $A$ in a new 'frame of reference'. Looking now at the expression $x_1B_1+\dots+x_nB_n$ it seems like this can be just about any vector I want since $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are arbitrary. This all leaves me a bit confused as I can then basically get any vector I want on the right side of the inequality and therefore be able to get a smaller norm than on the left. Any help? I **don't** want someone to prove it for me, but just to help me understand what the problem means or maybe a small hint to lead me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't write on books.

Comment: It's a PDF file.

Comment: Like the way you've **just** asked for the hint. (+1)

Comment: @Bryan  "I can then basically get any vector I want on the right side of the inequality", not so. Note that $m\leq n$ and $A$ has a unique representation (up to commutation of $+$ and $\cdot$) as a sum of a vector in the span of $\{B_1,\ldots ,B_m\}$ and a sum of of a vector in the perpendicular space of the previous set.

Comment: @BryanUrizar This can even be looked at as the reciprocal of the previous exercise.

Comment: People are incredibly prejudiced against pdf files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quantity $c_1 B_1 + \ldots + c_m B_m$ is what is called the *orthogonal projection* of the vector $A$ onto the subspace spanned by $B_1, \ldots, B_m$.

If this subspace were a plane, and $A$ were a vector "sticking out" of said plane, then the orthogonal projection of $A$ onto this plane would be the shadow of $A$ lying in the plane. See this picture (courtesy of Stanford):

[image]

Here $x$ is what you call $A$, and $\hat{x}$ is what you call $c_1 B_1 + \ldots + c_m B_m$. The flat surface is supposed to represent the subspace spanned by $B_1, \ldots, B_m$, so the orthogonal projection $\hat{x}$ onto this plane represents the largest portion of $x$ that is contained in the plane.

Comment: @GitGud Yes, you're right.

Comment: @Wong Thank you very much for your answer. The solution then comes from realizing that if $x'=x_1B_1+\ldots+x_mB_m$ then $(\hat{x} - x')\cdot (A-\hat{x})= 0$ and then it follows from 1.4.16.